# Probability based function in Node.JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, sorting

I wanted to create a function that when clicking when opening a chest, the person will get a random character, based on their probability of each class:

1 - Common: 90%
2 - Rare: 8%
3 - Super rare: 2%

Is this possible in Node.JS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's indeed possible, and in any language since that's just generating a random number (see [Math.Random()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random)) and doing some maths!

Here's an example with the code commented to explain what's going on:

```js
 // The actual function to draw a character class
function drawCharacterClass() {
  // We generate a random number between 0 and 1
  const r = Math.random();
  // If the number is between 0 and 0.02 (included) - so 2% chance
  if (r <= 0.02)
    return "Super Rare";
  // If the number is between 0.02 (not included) and 0.10 - so 8% chance.
  if (r <= 0.10)
    return "Rare";
  // If the number is anything else, so between 0.10 (not included) and 1 - so 90% chance.
  else
    return "Common";
}

// ===== ===== ===== Testing code below ===== ===== =====

// Now let's make a function that draw a lot of characters and record how many of each we got, this way we can make sure the drawCharacterClass() function is correct
function checkProbabilities(sample) {
  const res = {};
  for (let i = 0; i < sample; ++i) {
    const c = drawCharacterClass();
    res[c] = ++res[c] || 0;
  }
  return res;
}

// Let's poll 10 million characters.
// The higher the number the more precise it will be, but also slower.
const records = checkProbabilities(10000000);
// We count the total. We could also just use 10000000 directly.
const total = records["Common"] + records["Rare"] + records["Super Rare"];

// Now for each class of character, we count the amount we got from this class (records[class]) divided by the total of characters drawn. This will tell us what % of this class of character got drawn among the 10 millions draws.
console.log(`${Math.round(records["Common"] / total * 100)}% of Common.`); // Should say 90%
console.log(`${Math.round(records["Rare"] / total * 100)}% of Rare.`); // Should say 8%
console.log(`${Math.round(records["Super Rare"] / total * 100)}% of Super Rare.`); // Should say 2%
```

You can execute this code, will simulate the draw of 10 millions characters (might take a few seconds) using the function at the top of the snippet, and then calculate the effective drop rate of each character class, allowing you to make sure they are correct.

---

Note that this function `drawCharacterClass()` is very straightforward and only respect what you said in the question. Its goal is just to show you that "yes, it's possible", but it's by far **not the best way to do it**, especially if you plan to change the percentages, the names of the classes, add another class, etc...

In this case you might better do a more modular/generic approach so that for example you need only to change something like this:

```js
const classes = {
  "Common": 0.90,
  "Rare": 0.08,
  "Super Rare": 0.02
}
```

Also note that it will only draw a certain class of character, not the character itself.
But now that you know how to pick a randomized item among others (here a class among several classes), picking one character among several characters shouldn't be very hard!

Comment: My idea is when it enters the condition it will fetch the class from the bank and send a random character based on the condition.

Comment: Yes that could work! You could then have another function `drawCharacter(class)` that will draw a random character of a certain class from the bank. Then you would first call `drawCharacterClass()`, get a class from the bank, then call `drawCharacter(class)` with the class previously fetched and get a character!